# "Experienced the *fastest* growth"?

Tags: grammaticality, superlatives

I have a question about this sentence:

> Canada experienced the fastest growth in Internet usage.

From what I know about superlatives, the grammar structure is: S + *be* + *the* + adj. Therefore I am confused about the example. Is the sentence correct?

Comment: "Don't learn grammar from the *cheapest* book you can find." :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's grammatical. The use of superlative adjectives is not confined to the structure you describe.

Comment: Compare: John bought the biggest pumpkin (in the supermarket).

Answer (score 2):

For using superlatives, there is no formula *S + be + the + adj.* Although this is common, it is not a rule.

The only "rules" are that the comparison is between *at least two*, and you can use the *adj. + -est*, or *most* or *least*.

> My *most embarrassing* mistake tonight was forgetting the name of the hostess.
>
> My *biggest* mistake tonight was forgetting the name of our hostess.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you gave is A valid structure, but it is not the ONLY valid structure.

Grammatically, you can use a superlative in any or almost any sentence structure in which you could use an adjective. Of course the specific words have to make sense in context, but a superlative is an adjective and can be used like one.

There's the structure you gave: "Our Internet is fast." "Our Internet is the fastest."

But adjectives are used in many other ways. "Today I drove a red car." "Today I drove the fastest car."

"Bob, a bald man, took off his hat." "Bob, the biggest man, took off his hat."

Etc etc.